# How does expressions get executed?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, clr

As C# is not a language like python or Clojure, those could be evaluated in the REPLs. Then, how does the expression we write in the **watch** window or any evaluators window for that matter being executed on the fly?

It might be very obvious but I could not figure out.

**Edit:** Functions are not first class citizen in C#. Whenever we attach breakpoint, execution stops and we have the current context from the thread which is running, and whenever we do change the variable value, that's how it's updating the value in the thread/stack. I would like to understand how does the expression I write in the window, is getting executed, internally.

Such as simple expression like following,

```
2 == 2
```

Is the debugger creating a static class and static method to execute the expression? In order to run in CLR, it needs to compiled, so how does it work?

Thanks for your time in advance. :)

Comment: Expressions are compiled on the fly on first use.

Answer (score 0):

When you run application in debugging mode, debugger is attached to your application, which keeps track of current application state in real time. I saves information about which expression is currently executed on each thread, where variables are stored in memory, etc... this information is updated on each instruction execution in compiled code (IL). So when execution is paused and you execute some expression, for example you change value of local variable x. So you execute expression, let's say `x = 5`, at this point debugger already knows where x is stored in stack, so he can compile our expression and "inject" it to current process.